# Undefined variable: result in opencart 2.3

Tags: php, variables, undefined, opencart2.x

I have a problem with the opencart 2.3

> Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\thamr\catalog\controller\extension\module\featured.php on line 69Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\thamr\catalog\controller\extension\module\featured.php on line 69Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\thamr\catalog\controller\extension\module\featured.php on line 69Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\thamr\catalog\controller\extension\module\featured.php on line 69Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\thamr\catalog\controller\extension\module\featured.php on line 69Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\thamr\catalog\controller\extension\module\featured.php on line 69Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\thamr\catalog\controller\extension\module\featured.php on line 69

featured.php

```
$data['products'][] = array(
    'product_id'  => $product_info['product_id'],
    'thumb'       => $image,
    'name'        => $product_info['name'],
    'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',
    'price'       => $price,
    'special'     => $special,
    'tax'         => $tax,
    'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,   
    'rating'      => $rating,
    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_info['product_id'])
```

Comment: The `$result` variable is undefined

Comment: Thank you
I changed $result['minimum'] to $product_info['minimum']
It works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error message is telling you the `$result` variable is undefined.

Define it before you use it in your array.